# Creating line chart with multiple lines

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

Looking over [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/linemark/init(x:y:series:)) I found a straightforward way of doing this provided your dataset is structured correctly (mine is not).  I've been working with a CSV file containing rows structured as below:

```
PM2.5 data, PM10 data, DateTime
PM2.5 data, PM10 data, DateTime
...
```

And I've parsed each row into a `Measurement` object:

```
struct Measurement: Identifiable {
    var id: String // time of measurement 
    var pm25: Float
    var pm10: Float
}
```

I naively assumed I could just add multiple line marks as so (`measurements` is an array of `Measurement` objects):

```
            Chart(measurements){
                LineMark (
                    x: .value("Time", $0.id),
                    y: .value("PM2.5", $0.pm25)
                )
                
                LineMark (
                    x: .value("Time", $0.id),
                    y: .value("PM2.5", $0.pm10)
                )
            }
```

But this does not create multiple lines. Can anyone provide any suggestions on how to achieve this using Swift Charts in Swift UI? I found many solutions on Stack Overflow but they are for Swift 4 or older, nothing for SwiftUI.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you could try this simple approach, using the `series` version of `LineMark`:

```
Chart(measurements) {
    LineMark(
        x: .value("Time", $0.id),
        y: .value("PM2.5", $0.pm25),
        series: .value("pm25", "A")  // <-- here
    ).foregroundStyle(.red)
    
    LineMark(
        x: .value("Time", $0.id),
        y: .value("PM1.0", $0.pm10),
        series: .value("pm10", "B")   // <-- here
    ).foregroundStyle(.green)
}
```